# Android SDK tools crash on startup

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to run my android SDK tools. When they startup they crash with this error. It happens no matter if I run it from the terminal or if I launch it from Android Studio.

```
Jareds-Mac-mini:~ jared$ android 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff9b25482f, pid=71482, tid=8207
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AppKit+0x53382f]  -[NSDatePickerCell(NSTextFieldWithStepperDatePickerInternal) _concoctUnholyAbominationOfADateFormatThatMakesAMockeryOfLocalization]+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/jared/hs_err_pid71482.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abort trap: 6
```

The OS X error report is in this paste bin
https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8831994

Comment: Hey Jared, did you just download this SDK for the first time or were you updating?

Comment: I had the tools previously installed and working in the past. They just decided to stop working lol

Comment: In the past? Have you tried deleting your SDK folder and downloading from scratch?

Comment: I installed my SDK with Android Studio. Where would my tools be located? I am on a Mac.

Comment: Go to your preferences. Type SDK and you should be able to find it.

Comment: I located it and reinstalled everything but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be for you to reinstall your Java JDK and Java SE.

Comment: Java works because I can launch apps that require Java.

Comment: What does that error report say?

Comment: I fixed it by simply restarting my computer. The error report paste bin link is above. PS our names are both Jared :D

Comment: Yeah I noticed ha. Post an answer from you found!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the android SDK and tools. I then restarted my Mac twice and it started working. I can't seem to find out why it happened but it's fixed now. The error logs are open for you to view.